# Django says "no changes detected" in django tutorial when migrating

Tags: python, django

I'm doing the Django tutorial from their website.
When I type `python manage.py makemigrations polls`, django responds with `No changes detected in app 'polls'`. Same if I do `python manage.py makemigrations polls`

- I added `'polls.apps.PollsConfig'` in `mysite/settings.py`'s `INSTALLED_APPS` (I also tried with only `'polls'`)
- My `polls/models.py` is not empty
- `path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),` was added to `mysite/urls.py`
- I tried deleting migration folders content, ***pycache**, *.pyc, and db.sqlite3

Where could my mistake be ?

PS: I read all topic about this on Stackoverflow, tried everything and nothing worked

=== SOME MORE INFOS ===

Some commands I tried

```
bash $ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

```
bash $ ./manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
polls
 (no migrations)
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

```
bahs $ ./manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

```
bash $ ./manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Also:
from settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls', # also tried with 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

polls/models.py

```py
# polls/models.py
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

```
bash $ rm -rf polls/migrations
bash $ ./manage.py makemigrations polls
No changes detected in app 'polls'
bash $ ./manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero
CommandError: No installed app with label 'APPNAME'.
bash $ ./manage.py migrate --fake polls zero
CommandError: App 'polls' does not have migrations.
```

Comment: run `python manage.py showmigrations` and post the output here.

Comment: Done and added to post

Comment: Add the models of `polls` as well.

Comment: OK, it is added

Answer (score -1):

First, delete migration folder in polls

Then run python manage.py makemigrations polls

Next: python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero

Comment: @Thibault,  Do you have `migrations` directory now, under polls app folder??